# How to make App service virtual network swift connection when NSG association with subnet is mandatory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

Working on project where a custom policy enforces the subnet and nsg association. If subnet doesn’t have NSG associated with it then cannot be provisioned.

Used terraform to deploy resources- resource group, VNET, NSG and before Subnet is created I created NSG associated to Subnet as part of VNET deployment,deployed an app service plan, web app and then tried doing app service virtual network swify connection but it fails because service delegation is missing.

*terraform script*

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version                    = "=2.0.0"
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = var.resourceGroupName
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "main" {
  name                = var.nsgName
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "443"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "10.1.0.0/26"
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "NonProduction"
  }
}
data "azurerm_network_security_group" "main" {
  name                = azurerm_network_security_group.main.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = var.vNetName
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.1.0.4", "10.1.0.5"]
  subnet {
    name           = var.subNetName
    address_prefix = "10.1.0.0/26"
    security_group = data.azurerm_network_security_group.main.id
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "NonProduction"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "main" {
  name                = var.appServicePlanName
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_app_service" "main" {
  name                = var.appServiceName
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.main.id
  https_only          = true
}
data "azurerm_subnet" "main" {
  name                 = var.subNetName
  virtual_network_name = var.vNetName
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "main" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.main.id
  subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.main.id
}
```

Only thing I am unable to figure out is how to apply service delegation. I could have easily done this if the custom policy which enforces NSG before subnet creation was not there

*terraform script*

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "uksouth"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "acctestvnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test1" {
  name                 = "acctestsubnet1"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"

  delegation {
    name = "acctestdelegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "test" {
  name                = "acctestasp"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "test" {
  name                = "acctestas"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.test.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "test" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.test.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.test1.id
}
```

I could have used below tf config to set NSG association if required

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}
```

but problem with this approach is that association will happen post Subnet deployment but since custom policy is in place tf apply fails with policy violation error

Is there any way I can associate NSG before subnet creation and also apply service delegation?

Comment: can you share the terrafrom error you receive during the subnet creation?

Comment: Error creating App Service "acctestas" (Resource Group "terraform-VNET-webApp-Rg"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: Code="RequestDisallowedByPolicy" Message="Resource 'acctestas' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your custom policy required that the NSG needs to be associated with the subnet creation time or before the subnet is created. You have to use [azurerm_virtual_network](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_network.html) block to create the subnet and security group.

In this case, you could use [local-exec Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to invoke a local executable [CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#automation) after a resource is created.

**Example**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "acctestvnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

 subnet {
   name = var.subnet
   address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
   security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.main.id
 }

}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "test" {
  name                = "acctestas"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.test.id

provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "az webapp vnet-integration add --name ${azurerm_app_service.test.name} --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}  --vnet ${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name} --subnet ${var.subnet}"
  interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-command" ]
}

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution Nancy but I am facing issue "exec: "PowerShell": executable file not found in %PATH%. Output:" I have added C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe to the system path variable but no luck, any suggestion what could be missing in my local?

Comment: Do you run terraform .tf files on PowerShell? You can navigate to the directory where terraform.exe file exists to run your terraform file and also add the terraform.exe path to the system path variable..

Comment: I have to specify full powershell EXE path also I faced another issue where tf could not find resource group while doing doing vnet integration after I specified --subscription then it worked. Now I am not sure how this will work in AzDevOps, is there anyway to we can setup subscription context in local exec? 

I can create another variable but it will be better if I can find out subscription id dyanamically and pass to az webapp vnet-integration add

Comment: I have not used devops yet.

Comment: thanks how about setting context while running local exec for az webapp vnet-integration add --name ${azurerm_app_service.main.name} --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}  --vnet ${azurerm_virtual_network.main.name} --subnet ${var.subNetName} --subscription 'someid' I wants to read subscriptionid based on resource group

Comment: if az webapp support subscription parameter，you can decalare a variable for that.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggetions and help I have done it by using subscription variable.